# Chrome app closing window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Ok so i am a beginner programmer and was using the template google gave me to make a test app. I wanted that whenn someone clicked a text button, that it would close the window. The window uses HTML coding. i used:

```
<a href="JavaScript:window.close()">CLOSE</a>
```

Please help

Comment: Is this a Chrome packaged app or a website?

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:java]. Please, for the love of all that is holy, recognize that `java != javascript`! See [What's the difference between Java and JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java) for more details (specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/732016)).

Answer (score 6):

Open Chrome's javascript console in the [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) for your app by right clicking and selecting Inspect Element, then clicking on 'console' in the top list of tabs. You will see:

> Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

In a packaged app, due to the stricter [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_csp.html), you are not able to use javascript in an HTML file. You must create your HTML and then from a javascript file find the element and register an onclick handler.

For an example, see the [Window State](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/window-state) sample packaged app, look at [window.html](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/window-state/window.html) and [window.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/window-state/window.js).

`window.close()` will work from a javascript file. Though, you should be aware of the packaged app specific [app window api](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window.html) and see the other options there, such as `chrome.app.window.current().fullscreen()`.

Answer (score 4):

> **EDIT:** As pointed out by [Zibri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236062/zibri) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578121/chrome-app-closing-window/16578146?noredirect=1#comment89759472_16578146), this no longer works as of Chrome 67 on Linux (and possibly earlier). This answer is now obsolete. I retain the original text for posterity.

---

Google Chrome often doesn't let you close the window with `window.close` in JavaScript.

A workaround is to use:

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
```

You can try it out right now: enter `javascript:window.close();` into your address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and nothing will happen, but try this and it'll work:

```
javascript:window.open('','_self','');window.close();
```

See ["`window.close` method of JavaScript not working in Google Chrome"](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GjsCrvPYGlA) for more info.

Comment: Any idea if Google will stop this in future? I'd like to use this code but am worried it will stop working in future versions.

Comment: I get "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."

Comment: Confirmed that this no longer works (Chrome 67 on Linux). Thanks, @Zibri; I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new way to close windows using the new method `window.close()` in the dev version of Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/app.window.html#type-AppWindow.

But I'd recommend using WChargin's answer as it will work right now.